# [] parameter or input used in sum() function - what is it doing?

Tags: python

I am looking at the following page by a regular stackoverflow user, Peter Norvig, here:  http://norvig.com/sudoku.html

In this code, Peter has used the following code:

```
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s], [])) - set([s])) for s in squares)
```

`units` is a dictionary of 'columns', 'rows' and '9*9 squares' on the sudoku board and `squares` is all possible row/column combinations.

I don't understand the sum notation `sum(units[s], [])`   If I remove the `, []` phrase I get an error:

> "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'"

Using `help(sum)` returns

> sum(iterable, start=0, /)
>
> Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers
>
> When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
>      This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
>      reject non-numeric types.

So my question is, "what is the `[]` doing in this function?" Obviously it's an empty list, but is it a parameter of the `sum()` function or is it a value to add to `units[s]` ?  The python documentation is relatively 'quiet' on this, unless I'm simply not understanding it.... https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: I just played around with sum a bit and sum([[1,2]]) returns the same error, while sum([[1,2]],[]) does not. What do you get when you print out units[s]?

Comment: Note, this is a terrible antipattern. This will give you a quadratic time algorithm when a naive loop will give you linear time. *Don't use this*

Comment: @juanpa Is `itertools.chain` a better substitute?

Comment: @wjandrea yes, or just a loop with `.extend`, or a nested list comprehension. There are many better ways.

Comment: I didn't grasp the meaning of this entire comment:  "Note, this is a terrible antipattern. This will give you a quadratic time algorithm when a naive loop will give you linear time. Don't use this" - can you explain this comment to lesser mortals, please?

Answer (score 5):

Sum uses the `+` operator for summation. `+` is overloaded in `list`s for extending lists

```
>>> sum([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So `sum(units[s], [])` is trying to concat a list of iterables (`units[s]`) into a `list` .

You're getting that error probably because, `units[s]` is an integer for some reason, while it's supposed to be a `list`

Answer (score 4):

> is it a parameter of the `sum()` function or is it a value to add to `units[s]`?

It's *both*: you pass it as a parameter to the function, which then does its own business and, as per the docs, "return[s] the sum of a 'start' value plus an iterable of numbers", that is:

```
sum([1,2,3,4,5], start) == start + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
```

Some other types other than numbers support addition as well, such as lists:

```
[] + [1] + [2,3] == [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Understood --- "but why?"   Why do you have to stipulate an empty list in order for the sum function to work on the first parameter?  Isn't sum(x) == sum(x + None) ?   Why does it need the [] bit to work?

Comment: @lb_so, because it's impossible to add a `list` and `None`, yet you need something to `start` with, something that also doesn't change the resulting sum (a "zero" element). The empty list perfectly satisfies these requirements: 1) adding two lists is valid; 2) `[] + other_list == other_list`.